# In Apache Spark how to achieve --host [host] behavior on multiple workers with spark-env variable or with start-slaves.sh

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

In Spark standalone mode, when I start a worker with `start-slave.sh spark://master:7077` I can specify the host the worker listen on by `--host [host]`. This isn't practical if one has multiple workers.

How can I achieve that the workers appear in the master WebUI with the specified hostnames without starting them one-by-one?
Is there an environment variable for it?
Or can I pass somehow worker specific arguments to the starter script (`start-slaves.sh`)?

For example:

conf/slaves:

```
worker1
worker2
worker3
```

The cluster is started by `start-all.sh` and should have the same effect as (notice the -h argument):

```
ssh worker1 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh -h worker1 spark://master:7077
ssh worker2 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh -h worker2 spark://master:7077
ssh worker3 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh -h worker4 spark://master:7077
```

By default the workers are reported by their IP address, which I want to substitute with firendly names from `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found is to set SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME in spark-env.sh on slave nodes.